# test my firebase auth triggers locally

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I would like to test some firebase database and auth triggers locally and have found this documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions.

Following along the instructions I typed

```
firebase functions:shell
```

and then invoked my custom firebase trigger with

```
createNewUser({user: {email: 'some@email.com'}},{auth: {uid: '123'}})
```

However, this gives me the error

```
firebase > createNewUser({user: {email: 'some@email.com'}},{auth: {uid: '123'}})
'Successfully invoked function.'
firebase > info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Function crashed
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null
```

This is the function I try to run:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.createNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  let lowerCaseEmail = user.email.toLowerCase();
  return admin.database().ref(`/users/${user.uid}/lowerCaseEmail`).set(lowerCaseEmail);
});
```

I believe I don't invoke my custom function correctly in firebase functions:shell.

Would someone like to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add your Cloud Function code to your post?

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec, I added the code of my cloud function to the question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: As far as I can see, you're nesting `user`. So you'll need:

    let lowerCaseEmail = user.user.email.toLowerCase()

Comment: Thanks for your insight @FrankvanPuffelen! According to Renauds answer i think i did not pass the correct arguments to my trigger function.. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the documentation you have to pass a `UserRecord` (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord)) when invoking an Auth function, see at the bottom of the doc you point to in your Question (i.e. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#invoke_realtime_database_functions)

Doing the following works:

```
createNewUser({ disabled: false, 
                displayName: 'Renaud', 
                email: 'Mail@Gmail.com', 
                emailVerified: false, 
                metadata: {creationTime: null, lastSignInTime: null}, 
                photoURL: null, 
                providerData: ['google.com'], 
                uid: '123' })
```

You do find the new record in the database, with the email in lower case.

---

Actually, since the documentation says: "Specify only the fields that your code depends on, or none at all if you only want to run the function.", I've tried with the following `UserRecord` object, and **it also works**.

```
createNewUser({email: 'Mail@Gmail.com', uid: '123'})
```